# C# List<Dictionary<string,string>> - how to extract unique key/value pairs

Tags: c#

In a C# List>, how can I extract unique key/value pairs and store it in List>?

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> md = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

### Input

md[0] :

```
[0]:"A","Apple"
[1]:"B","Ball"
```

md[1]:

```
[0]:"A","Apple"
[1]:"B","Ball"
```

md[2]:

```
[0]: "C", "Cat"
[1]: "D", "Dog"
```

### Output

md[0] :

```
[0]:"A","Apple"
[1]:"B","Ball"
```

md[1]:

```
[0]:"C" : "Cat"
[1]:"D" : "Dog"
```

Code sample to extract both unique key/value pairs are needed, only unique keys or unique values are not needed.

(* Note : [0],[1] above depicts the indexes in the list and dictionary and not the keys or values)

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: What if the second dictionary contains `{"A", "Apple"}, {"B", "Banana"}`? Will the second value considered unique?

Comment: More importantly, what happens if you have `{"A", "AHole" }`, for example. Is it unique too?

Comment: {"A", "Apple"}, {"B", "Banana"}, {"A", "AHole" } are unique. Requirement is that both the key value pairs together should be unique.

Comment: Also, an additional requirement : I want to compare two list of dictionaries for equality. Can you please post a code sample for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it with linq.

```
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> md = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        md.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A","Apple"}, { "B", "Ball" } });
        md.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A","Apple"}, { "B", "Ball" } });
        md.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "C","Cat"}, { "D", "Dog" } });

        var filtered =
            md.GroupBy(x => string.Join("", x.Select(i => string.Format("{0}{1}", i.Key, i.Value)))).Select(x => x.First());
```

Variable "filtered" contains list of dictionaries with unique sets.

Comment: Many thanks Victor for the quick reply and a quick solution.

Comment: Also, an additional requirement : I want to compare two list of dictionaries for equality. Can you please post a code sample for that.

Comment: This may work well enough for you, but this answer is flawed - it's dependant on the how the dictionary was constructed (try switching `"B"` and `"A"` in the second dictionary); it doesn't distinguish between e.g. `{"B","Ball"}` and `{"BB","all"}`; and in contrived cases it's even possible for dictionaries with different numbers of entries to be considered equal, e.g. `{{"A","App"},{"le",B"},{"B","all"}}`.

Comment: This assumes that if `i.Key+i.Value==j.Key+j.Value`, then `i.Key==j.Key&&i.Value==j.Value`. This may work for the OP's specific input, but doesn't work in general, and that should be called out IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> md = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();

var unique = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var m in md)
{
    foreach(var innerKey in m.Key)
    {
      if (!unique.ContainsKey(innerKey))
      {
        unique.Add(innerKey, m[innerKey]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hristo for your quick reply. I would go with the shorter LINQ solution posted by Victor below. Thanks to u too for your quick solution!

Answer (score 0):

One possible strictly correct solution would be to implement `IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>`:

```
public class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, string> d)
    {
        var hashCode = 17;
        foreach (var entry in d.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key))
        {
            hashCode = hashCode * 23 + entry.Key.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * 23 + entry.Value.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }

    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, string> d1, Dictionary<string, string> d2)
    {
        string value2;
        return d1.Count == d2.Count && d1.All(kvp => d2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value2) && kvp.Value == value2);
    }
}
```

Then to get your list of unique dictionaries:

```
var result = md.Distinct(new DictionaryComparer()).ToList();
```